# Picture animation with jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement this code [animation link](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/)

I made a html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="work.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="rotateme();">

<img src="arrow.png" id="image">

</body>
</html>
```

a javascript file work.js:

```
var rotateme = function(){
var value = 0
$("#image").rotate({ 
bind: { 
    click: function(){
        value +=170;
        $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
    }
 } 
});}
```

a css file style.css:

```
#image{
margin:100px 100px;
}
```

The problem is when I execute my code, I got these error messages on the console:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined   **jquery.easing.min.js:46**
>   The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.    **index.html**
>   TypeError: $(...).rotate is not a function  **work.js:8**

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery BEFORE the other scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="work.js"></script>
```

The error tells you that the jquery.easing.min.js plugin is trying to use jQuery, but it doesn't yet exist because it's not yet included in the page

Comment: I changed the order of the scripts, and still no results:

**The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.html
TypeError: $(...).rotate is not a function work.js:9**

Comment: I tried to delete the onload event on the body tag (because the event click is already defined on the work.js file).... Only the first error message remain ( **The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The doc...**)

Comment: @user1444393 try to adding above meta Tags in your html file

Comment: I modified my code like this: [my code][1]


Now, I have no error message in the console but no result neither... my picture didn't rotate!


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/98Ab6UDv

Comment: Refer my Answer. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Add this tags in your HTML inside head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

Call this way because you need to define jquery first and then call other libraries

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="work.js"></script>
```

Put your code inside $(document).ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var value = 0
$("#image").rotate({
bind:
 {
    click: function(){
        value +=170;
        $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
    }
 }

 });
 });
```

if Still you have a problem. download working file from below path

[**File Download**](http://speedy.sh/UU4bK/Jquery-Animation.zip)